# linux bridge two NICs with multiple VLANs and assign virtual IP

Tags: linux-networking

I'm trying to do some testing of linux bridging.  I have a server with two NICs (eth1/eth2) and i want to bridge together, use multiple VLAN tags and assign an IP to a virtual interface in each VLAN for me to ping.

I have this so far:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
bridge vlan add dev br0 vid 1000 self
bridge vlan add dev br0 vid 1001 self
bridge vlan add dev eth1 vid 1000 pvid
bridge vlan add dev eth2 vid 1000 pvid
bridge vlan add dev eth1 vid 1001 pvid
bridge vlan add dev eth2 vid 1001 pvid
```

The bridge looks ok to me

```
bash-5.0# bridge vlan
port    vlan ids
eth1     1000 PVID
         1001 PVID

eth2     1000 PVID
         1001 PVID

br0  1000 PVID
     1001 PVID
```

But now i want to put something i can ping into vlan 1000 and vlan1001 to test
Was trying to do this with a dummy interface but can't seem to make that work

Any tips?  I believe the bridge config is good.  We're expecting everything to be tagged

Comment: Can you provide you GNU/Linux distribution.

Comment: running Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a trunk mode with allowed VLANs 1000 and 1001 with LACP port-channel on your switch side?

if you are not using netplan, here is a network configuration file for you:

```
user@ubuntu-01:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
         slaves eth0 eth1
         bond_mode 802.3ad
         bond_miimon 100

auto vlan1000
iface vlan1000 inet manual
         vlan_raw_device bond0

auto vlan1001
iface vlan1001 inet manual
         vlan_raw_device bond0

auto br1000
iface br1000 inet static
        bridge_ports vlan1000
        address 192.168.1.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.254
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto xenbr1001
iface xenbr1001 inet manual
        bridge_ports vlan1001
#IP IF NEEDED
#otherwise you may assign this bridge to the related VMs, containers etc
        address 192.168.2.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

To apply just use ifup:
sudo ifup bond0;
sudo ifup br1000;
sudo ifup br1001;

OR

Restart network service

OR

Reboot the machine

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is use netplan.

I let you a example of how configure a VLAN using Netplan, To create a VLAN Interface you need follow these basic steps:

1. Configure a Bridge Interface this is because virtual interfaces exist on the same physical interface
2. Create sub interface to link a specific VLAN.
3. Configure each sub interface and asign to virtual interface
4. Link each virtual interface to VLAN ID and Physical interface

---

```
network:
ethernets:
    # Disable DHCP to set IP address on interface enp6s0f0
    enp6s0f0:
        dhcp4: false
    # Disable DHCP to set IP address on interface enp6s0f1
    # Set Static IP Address.
    enp6s0f1:
        dhcp4: false
        addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.0.254
bridges:
     # Create Bridge br0 on enp6s0f0
     br0:
       # Allow Bridge interface get IP address from DHCP using VLAN 0 / not tag
       dhcp4: true
       dhcp6: false
       interfaces: [enp6s0f0]
     # Create Bridge br0.10
     br0.10:
       # Link br0.10 to Virtual Interface vlan.10 this is a name only
       interfaces: [vlan.10]
       # Set static IP address on Virtual Interface            
       addresses: [192.168.1.10/24]
       gateway4: 192.168.1.254
       nameservers:
         addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
       parameters:
              stp: false
              forward-delay: 0
     # Create Bridge interface br0.20
     br0.20:
       # Link br0.20 to Virtual Interface vlan.20 this is a name only
       interfaces: [vlan.20]
       parameters:
              stp: false
              forward-delay: 0

#Link virtual interface to VLAN
vlans:
      # Link virtual interface vlan.10 and VLAN 10
      vlan.10:
          link: enp6s0f0
          id: 10
      # Link virtual interface vlan.20 and VLAN 20
      vlan.20:
          link: enp6s0f0
          id: 20
version: 2
```

---

> In this example the some virtual interfaces doesn't have IP address. If you need set a IP address the address is set on sub interfaces **br0.X**.

[Netplan Doc](https://netplan.io/examples/)